# Windows 10 scheduled task run as admin user wont execute powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have a windows 10 task that Im trying to set to run as a domain user that is also in the local admin group on the machine im running it.  The action is running a powershell script. I know the script works fine as when I run the task under my account, it works fine.  When running it as the domain account it seems to do nothing.  Where can I check for error messages? 
One action I set before calling the script is also using powershell and sets the execution policy to unrestricted.  Shouldnt being in the local admin group be sufficient permissions for this?

Here is the powershell script

```
Echo "test"
Read-Host -Prompt "press any key to exit"
```

Comment: How can you expect an answer if you don't show us this script?

Comment: Have you checked the option "Run this task with administrative privileges"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 actions
(1) Powershell:
command =

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

(2) Powershell:
run a script that has

```
Echo "test"
Read-Host -Prompt "press any key to exit"
```

(3) Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Restricted

What I was missing was on the 1st step

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

Comment: The problem with setting the `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` is that it changes the **overall** security level for script execution so you also should set it back to restricted once you run the script or else the overall security stays unrestricted. Unlike in my answer where you use the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` it just bypasses the execution policy restriction for only that run/session of script execution without affecting the overall security of the execution policy so no need to revert back afterwards and no need to compromise security defaults.