# Windows task using domain account results in user profile error event id 1511

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-domain, windows-task-scheduler

This is on *Windows 2012 Server Datacenter*

Have a windows task setup to run under a specific domain account.
Security options = Run whether the user is logged on or not and "run with highest privileges" checked. This account is also a local admin.

The task executes a powershell script that works fine when I invoke it manually

The task has 3 actions and are listed here:

```
Start a program powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
Start a program powersehll .\myscript.ps1
Start a program powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

This seemed to work fine when I setup this same task on another machine, as well as my own workstation.  However, on this particular server, I get errors in the windows event log in pairs.  One is an explicit entry that Im writing to the event log from within the powershell script within a try/catch, but the other is an error with EventID 1511 from the User Profile Service.
"*Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off*."

The other error that I am logging is due to the webrequest, and its getting a http 401 error.

This account was setup as a domain service account.  What could be causing this issue with the user profile?  I suspect that since our domain controller is still on 2008, this might be related?

Comment: bitshift - I told you in my answer of this post how to get this to work so please take two minutes, do a quick test, and confirm. http://superuser.com/questions/1179277/windows-10-scheduled-task-run-as-admin-user-wont-execute-powershell/1180092#1180092 ... Additionally, per a automated `Invoke-WebRequest` processes I setup for a company for automation I use format such as `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -TimeoutSec 300` and I put that within a TRY CATCH block to do something different on error exception. Increase the `TimeoutSec`. The domain is 2008 DCs there too btw.

Comment: The temporary profile fix is a common issue that's easy to fix usually by simply deleting the applicable registry key in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` location.

Comment: Another thing to note regarding Task Scheduler and PowerShell script execution that's worked for me in the past... https://i.imgur.com/3vC93mu.png and note the values of the `Program/script` and `Add arguments (optional)` fields. Another thing that's easy enough to try... Point to the full explicit path to the PS1 file and the PowerShell.exe executable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with only a single action rather than three.

**Program/script:** `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

**Add argumments (optional):** `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File MyScript.ps1`

**Start in (optional):** *path where myscript.ps1 sits*